# Basic AUCTeX Setup Issue in macOS and Linux

Tags: latex, auctex, osx

I'm trying to get AUCTeX up and running in macOS and linux and have followed the steps [here](http://www.wangzerui.com/2017/02/20/setting-up-a-nice-environment-for-latex-on-macos/).

(The site has a separate guide for GNU/Linux.) My problem remains invariant between OSes, so I'm asking for help.

In each instance, loading a .tex file, I note that Emacs shows my mode as `LaTeX/PS` -- should this not say AUCTeX?

In any case, `C-c C-c` brings up `Command (default latexmk)`, and another `C-c C-c` is undefined.

Any suggestions where something might be amiss?

Comment: How about first getting one OS Emacs setup up and running correctly and then work on the second OS, so that your questions is not overly broad?  I.e., you are presently unclear whether either setup is correct and you want people to troubleshoot both setups, including, guessing which OS has `C-c C-c` being undefined.  Also, I seriously doubt that `latexmk` (a pearl script) is the default -- instead, the default is probably something like `pdflatex`.  I use `latexmk`, but had to configure this especially for my personal needs.

Comment: I mention both OSes only to indicate that my error is consistent -- not to overly confiscate the issue, though that seems to have happened nonetheless. In any case, I'm proceeding with macOS, and have made such a mess of my .emacs file that perhaps its best to start over. (If it's not clearly obvious, I'm new to emacs and the like. I've made my way through the tutorial, and am getting familiar with the editor. It's really nice, and I'd like to be able to set up a latex environment with it.)

Answer (score 2):

AUCTeX provides editing support for various TeX based formats, e.g. plain TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt etc.  LaTeX support is identified as `LaTeX` in mode line (note the camel case) in opposite to `latex` provided by Emacs itself.

`P` indicates that AUCTeX will produce a pdf file when you compile a file which is this line in the link you mention:

```lisp
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

`S` indicates that `TeX-source-correlate-mode` is activated with these lines:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
     '(TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
     '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
     '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t))
```

AUCTeX also will run `latexmk` by default which is this line:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))
```

AUCTeX seems to do exactly how you configured it to do.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks so much. My goal in using emacs was to set up a nice local latex environment, which has lead to a lot of copy/pasting code. It's nice to have a better sense of what it's actually doing.